# Display image from google search api in react

Tags: reactjs, google-image-search

I am creating a custom image search application. I have a search text field where the user enters the text and from my flask backend, I am using the [Google Image Search API](https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/) to get the images searched for. 
Now, I want to display these images on the front end, I am using React for my front end.

On the button click, I make the fetch call as below,

```
 fetch('localhost/image_search/'+this.state.inputQuery)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        images: result
                    })
                }
            );
```

I have 2 questions. 
How should I be sending the images from the backend? Send them as blobs?
Once I receive the image from the backend, how can they be displayed on the front end?

TL;DR, I am creating my own google search application to search for images on the web, once the user gives the search text, how can I display searched images on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the images as urls i.e. array of images

['https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2020/02/Google-Image-Search.jpg','https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2020/02/Google-Image-Search.jpg'];

Since, you are setting them to images in state, in your render method:

```
render(){
return{
{this.state.images.map((x,i)=>{
<img src={x} alt="image" key={i} />
});}
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, 
I did think of this, but I am not showing the images as-is from google search, I am applying some openCV functions to the image, and then showing them on the UI.